# Openshot bugs and crops some parts away

Tags: 16.04, openshot

In my Ubuntu, if I export a mp4 using Openshot, its not the same as I can see in the video preview, its shorter, I mean from every single clip there are a couple of seconds cropped away... Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution : FPS has to be 30, not 25, so 1/6 has been cropped from every snippet.